# Conditionally Add Prefix to Tokens in Comma-Separated String

Tags: c#, regex, preg-replace

example 91 is ISD code of India, below is list of comma seperated mobile numbers

9111111111,1111111112,1111111113,911111111114,911111111115

What is the best way to prefix 91 to phone numbers if not present. Below is expected output

919111111111,911111111112,911111111113,911111111114,911111111115

We can always split and loop through checking and replacing values and later concat them.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Making the assumption that telephone numbers are always the same length and 91 can only be the country code might cause problems. [Telephone numbers in India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_India)/[Mobile telephone numbering in India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India)

Comment: True. I am modifying the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Replacing a Position (Zero-Width) Match

Use this:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?=\b(?!91\d{10})\d{10}\b)", "91");
```

In **[the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aP0qH2/5)**, see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

The regex `(?=\b(?!91\d{10})\d{10}\b)` matches the position where we should insert `91`, without matching any characters. We replace that position match with `91`.

The lookahead `(?=\b(?!91\d{10})\d{10}\b)` asserts that what follows is

- `\b` a word boundary (ensuring we do not match at mid-string)
- `(?!91\d{10})` not followed by `91` and ten digits (negative lookehead) and
- `\d{10}` ten digits

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: So what if the actual phonenumber starts with 91?

Comment: @Jonathan From his question my understanding is that if it starts with `91`, we do nothing.

Comment: Hmmm...nice solution and explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged this [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), here's the regex way;

Replace `\b(\d{10})\b` with `91$1`

This will match and capture a series of 10 digits. The `91$1` replacement string will prefix it with `91`.

Comment: So what if the actual phonenumber starts with 91?

Comment: @Jonathan you're perfectly right, thanks. It looks like his phone numbers each have 10 digits, so I'll use that.

Comment: Thank you Lucas and Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define better but you can always use linq:

```
var numbers = input.Split(',').Select(x => x.StartsWith("91") ? x : "91" + x);

var result = string.Join(",", numbers);
```

Comment: So what if the actual phonenumber starts with 91?

Comment: Works too great. But Jonathan has a right question.